# jQuery price calculator function is not working with tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get this working from last couple of days without any success. I have this price calculator function developed by a freelancer who is not reachable from last few weeks.

This function works fine without any JavaScript tabs but not quite right with them. I need to have tabs on page because there are tons of options in this calculator.

This is the jQuery function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // For tabs
  var tabContents = $(".tab_content").hide(),
  tabs = $("ul.nav-tabs li");
  tabs.first().addClass("active").show();
  tabContents.first().show();
  tabs.click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
    activeTab = $this.find('a').attr('href');
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
      $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      tabContents.hide().filter(activeTab).fadeIn();
    }
    return false;
  });

  // For Calculator
  function Cost_Calculator() {

    var Currency = '$';
    var messageHTML = 'Please contact us for a price.';

    function CostFilter(e) {
      return e;
    }

    //Calculate function
    function calculate() {

      //Blank!
      var CalSaveInfo = [];
      $('#cost_calc_custom-data, #cost_calc_breakdown').html('');

      //Calculate total
      var calCost = 0;
      var calculate_class = '.cost_calc_calculate';
      $('.cost_calc_active').each(function() {

        //Calculation
        calCost = calCost + parseFloat($(this).data('value'));

        //Add to list
        var optionName = $(this).attr('value');
        var appendName = '<span class="cost_calc_breakdown_item">' + optionName + '</span>';

        var optionCost = $(this).attr('data-value');
        var appendCost = '<span class="cost_calc_breakdown_price">' + Currency + optionCost + '</span>';

        if (optionCost != "0") {
          var appendItem = '<li>' + appendName + appendCost + '</li>';
        }

        //hidden data
        var appendPush = ' d1 ' + optionName + ' d2 d3 ' + optionCost + ' d4 ';

        $('#cost_calc_breakdown').append(appendItem);

        CalSaveInfo.push(appendPush);

      });

      //Limit to 2 decimal places
      calCost = calCost.toFixed(2);

      //Hook on the cost
      calCost = CostFilter(calCost);

      var CustomData = '#cost_calc_custom-data';
      $.each(CalSaveInfo, function(i, v) {
        $(CustomData).append(v);
      });

      //Update price
      if (isNaN(calCost)) {
        $('#cost_calc_total_cost').html(messageHTML);
        $('.addons-box').hide();
      } else {
        $('#cost_calc_total_cost').html(Currency + calCost);
        $('.addons-box').show();
      }

    }

    //Calculate on click
    $('.cost_calc_calculate').click(function() {

      if ($(this).hasClass('single')) {
        //Add cost_calc_active class
        var row = $(this).data('row');
        //Add class to this only
        $('.cost_calc_calculate').filter(function() {
          return $(this).data('row') == row;
        }).removeClass('cost_calc_active');
        $(this).addClass('cost_calc_active');
      } else {
        // Remove class if clicked
        if ($(this).hasClass('cost_calc_active')) {
          $(this).removeClass('cost_calc_active');
        } else {
          $(this).addClass('cost_calc_active');
        }
      }

      //Select item
      var selectItem = $(this).data('select');
      var currentItem = $('.cost_calc_calculate[data-id="' + selectItem + '"]');
      var currentRow = currentItem.data('row');

      if (selectItem !== undefined) {
        if (!$('.cost_calc_calculate[data-row="' + currentRow + '"]').hasClass('cost_calc_active'))
          currentItem.addClass('cost_calc_active');
      }

      //Bring in totals & information
      $('#cost_calc_breakdown_container, #cost_calc_clear_calculation').fadeIn();
      $('.cost_calc_hide').hide();
      $('.cost_calc_calculate').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
          $(this).removeClass('cost_calc_active');
        }
        calculate();
      });

      return true;
    });

    $('#cost_calc_clear_calculation').click(function() {
      $('.cost_calc_active').removeClass('cost_calc_active');
      calculate();
      $('#cost_calc_breakdown').html('<p id="empty-breakdown">Nothing selected</p>');
      return true;
    });
  }

  //Run cost calculator
  Cost_Calculator();

});
```

You can see this working on [jsfiddle without tabs](http://jsfiddle.net/c6gdn7wd/). I can select options from multiple sections and order box will update selected option's price and details dynamically.

But when I add JavaScript tabs, it stop working correctly. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly5acLf4/). Now if I select option from different sections, order box resets previous selection and shows new one only.

I think the problem is with calculator somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing the `active` class from hidden elements. This means that when you move to the second tab you disregard what you've done in the first.

line 120 in your fiddle:

```
if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
      $(this).removeClass('cost_calc_active');
    }
```

I haven't taken the code in depth enough to tell if you can just remove this.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Although it will break a specific functionality of this calculator but I think on this project, I can live with that. :) Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear :-) if the answer helped you're welcome to accept it